# Science Fiction short story about cybernetic humans and their cybernetic dogs

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, cyborg

Trying to find a science fiction short story about a cybernetic human and his cybernetic dog. They were immortal and could speak to each other. It was in an anthology, so I can't remember the author or title. I remember at one point the man asks his dog what he thinks about time and the dog responds, "Tempus? Fugit!"

Comment: How long ago did you read it?

Comment: By the way, what do you mean by "cybernetic" humans and dogs? Do you mean that they were intelligent machines? Or do you mean cyborgs?